# Python setting attributes priority and overriding

Tags: python

I am really confused between these three methods

```
setattr()
__setattr__
obj.x = 10
```

I have this test class

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__['x'] = 99

b = Test()
#setattr(b,'x',10)
#b.x = 10
```

now i have two questions

b.x is converted to

`b.x = 10  -->  b.__setattr__(x,10) -->  b.__dict__['x'] = 10`

and setattr(b,'x',10) is also converted to

`setattr(b,'x',10)  -->  b.__setattr__(x,10) -->  b.__dict__['x'] = 10`

then why we use one over the other

1. which is the lowest level function so that no matter what how value to the varaible is assigned but my valued does not get chnages either with `b.x` or `sttattr` or `__setattr`

Comment: Your last sentence does not make sense, please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: i mean that the value of x should always be 10 no matter how user assigns the value

Comment: This `b.__setattr__(x,10) --> b.__dict__['x'] = 10` isn't correct. For example see [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__slots__#object.__slots__)

Comment: @user2082226: That still isn't clear.  Are you saying you want to set the attribute to 10 and make it impossible to change it?  You should just `__setattr__` and not worry about users trying to "hack" you by using things like `__dict__`.  If people use `__dict__` directly and something breaks, it's their own fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use `b.x = 10` when you know ahead of time (i.e., when writing the program) what attribute you are assigning to.  You use `setattr` when you don't know (for instance, if you are reading configuration information from a file or doing some sort of dynamic programming).

You would never literally do `setattr(b, 'x', 10)`, because if you could type that with a literal `x` in there, you could have just done `b.x = 10` and saved some typing.  You would use `setattr` for something like:

```
optionName, optionValue = readConfigFile()
setattr(configObject, optionName, optionValue)
```

That is, you use it when you don't know until runtime what attribute you'll be assigning to.  This might, for instance, be because it depends on external resources (as in my example), or on user input.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way is

```
b.x = 10
```

If you don't know the attribute name in advance

```
attr_name = 'x'
setattr(b, attr_name, 10)
```

Is a fine way to say the same thing.

This is not a good way to set the attribute on `b`.

```
b.__dict__['x'] = 10
```

As you are assuming that `b` has a `__dict__` attribute (not all objects do)

Comment: then when i can use `__setattr__` in class. any use case

Comment: @user2082226. `setattr(b, ...)` calls `Test.__setattr__(b, ...)`

Comment: Can i mention classname instead object instance in setattr so that i can assign the class attribute not the instance attribute

Comment: also as you mentioned which objects don't have the `__dict` , i thought eveyone has